# Equality operator on mixed types in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-api

[In chapter 13.2 of Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.2.html) it's stated that

> Unlike arithmetic metamethods, relational metamethods do not support mixed types.

and at the same time

> Lua calls the equality metamethod only when the two objects being compared share this metamethod

So I'm implementing my library in C and want to be able to support behavior like

```
a = A()
b = B()
a == b
```

by providing

```
static const struct luaL_Reg mylib_A[] =
{
  { "__eq", my_equal }
  , <more stuff>
  , { NULL, NULL }
};
```

and

```
static const struct luaL_Reg mylib_B[] =
{
  { "__eq", my_equal }
  , <more stuff>
  , { NULL, NULL }
};
```

Which doesn't seem to work, is there a workaround for this?
Note: my_equal is able to handle both userdata of type A and type B in any of it's arguments

UPDATE:
Metatables registration:

```
luaL_newmetatable(lua, "B");
lua_pushvalue(lua, -1);
lua_setfield(lua, -2, "__index");
luaL_register(lua, NULL, mylib_B);

luaL_newmetatable(lua, "A");
lua_pushvalue(lua, -1);
lua_setfield(lua, -2, "__index");
luaL_register(lua, NULL, mylib_A);

luaL_register(lua, "mylib", mylib); -- where mylib is a bunch of static functions
```

Application code:

```
require 'mylib'
a = mylib.new_A()
b = mylib.new_B()
a == b -- __eq is not called
```

Comment: what version of lua are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to support both 5.1 and 5.2

Comment: Are you setting `__eq` in the metatable of the object or in the object's methods/etc. table itself?

Comment: @whoever: as far as I know, the code you are posting should work, maybe you can post a MWE?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm using old-style luaL_register(L, NULL, mylib_A) to register the metatable, luaL_getmetatable and lua_setmetatble to create a userdata object if that helps to make it clearer

Comment: Show the metatable registration and application code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Also see [whoever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640632/501459) which has a particular caveat with regards to implementing `__eq` in the C API.

---

The `__eq` metamethod belongs in your metatable, not in the `__index` table.

In lua:

```
function my_equal(x,y)
    return x.value == y.value
end



A = {} -- luaL_newmetatable(lua, "A");
A.__eq = my_equal

function new_A(value)
    local a = { value = value }
    return setmetatable(a, A)
end


B = {} -- luaL_newmetatable(lua, "B");
B.__eq = my_equal

function new_B(value)
    local b = { value = value }
    return setmetatable(b, B)
end


a = new_A()
b = new_B()
print(a == b) -- __eq is called, result is true

a.value = 5
print(a == b) -- __eq is called, result is false
```

What *you* have done is this:

```
myLib_A = {}
myLib_A.__eq = my_equal

A = {} -- luaL_newmetatable(lua, "A");
A.__index = myLib_A
```

Note that `__eq` is *not* in A's metatable, it's on a totally separate table that you just be happen to be using in a different, unrelated metamethod (`__index`). Lua is not going to look there when trying to resolve the equality operator for `a`.

The Lua manual explains this in detail:

> "eq": the == operation. The function getcomphandler defines how Lua chooses a metamethod for comparison operators. A metamethod only is selected when both objects being compared have the same type and the same metamethod for the selected operation.

```
 function getcomphandler (op1, op2, event)
   if type(op1) ~= type(op2) then return nil end
   local mm1 = metatable(op1)[event]
   local mm2 = metatable(op2)[event]
   if mm1 == mm2 then return mm1 else return nil end
 end
```

> The "eq" event is defined as follows:

```
 function eq_event (op1, op2)
   if type(op1) ~= type(op2) then  -- different types?
     return false   -- different objects
   end
   if op1 == op2 then   -- primitive equal?
     return true   -- objects are equal
   end
   -- try metamethod
   local h = getcomphandler(op1, op2, "__eq")
   if h then
     return (h(op1, op2))
   else
     return false
   end
 end
```

So when Lua encounters `result = a == b`, it's going to do the following (this is done in C, Lua used as pseudocode here):

```
-- Are the operands are the same type? In our case they are both tables:
if type(a) ~= type(b) then
 return false
end

-- Are the operands the same object? This comparison is done in C code, so
-- it's not going to reinvoke the equality operator.
if a ~= b then
 return false
end

-- Do the operands have the same `__eq` metamethod?
local mm1 = getmetatable(a).__eq
local mm2 = getmetatable(b).__eq
if mm1 ~= mm2 then
 return false
end

-- Call the `__eq` metamethod for the left operand (same as the right, doesn't really matter)
return mm1(a,b)
```

You can see there's no path here that results in resolve `a.__eq`, which would resolve to `myLib_A` through your `__index` metamethod.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarifying it out, I really did expect it to check the __index'ed table. But now there seems to be something more with it: I restructured the code to self-assign __index of A to A itself and register all functions in A (so it goes like luaL_newmetatable, luaL_register, lua_setfield(L, -1, "__index") now), this works between instance_of_A_1 == instance_of_A_2, but still doesn't get called on instance_of_A == instance_of_B, any ideas?

Comment: new_A and new_B both create new userdata and assign the appropriate metatables to them via luaL_getmetatable, lua_setmetatable

Comment: Additionaly, getmetatable(a)["__eq"](a, b) calls the appropriate method, getmetatable(b)["__eq"](a, b) calls the appropriate method, but getmetatable(a)["__eq"] == getmetatable(window)["__eq"] evaluates to false! (which I suppose to be a reason why it doesn't get called) I'm somewhat in a loss here, any thoughts?

Comment: Don't know why you're mentioning `__index` still. It's not relevant to the `__eq` problem so it only distracts. Make sure you're not trying to resolve the metamethod through a metamethod. `__eq` should be a field directly on your metatable. `getmetatable(window)` has no meaning to me. It's the first time you've mentioned `window`.

Comment: `window` states for `b` there, only noticed it after 5 minute deadline on comment editing. I actually managed to track down the original problem thanks to your explanation of `getcomphandler` implementation. I'm not even sure whether there's a need to switch the accepted answer than, could you just perhaps link to mine's in the begining so that others will find it?

Comment: I don't mind if you switch answers. I don't care about StackOverflow points. But, sure, I'll link to yours.

Answer (score 2):

For all others who would be facing the same problem:
This was the only way how I made Lua aware of `my_equal` being the exact same function from the point of Lua in both cases and consequently returning correct operator from `getcomphandler`. Registering it in any other way (including separate `luaL_Reg`) doesn't work due to `my_equal` being saved under different closures upon `luaL_register`, which I here avoid by creating the closure only once.

```
// we'll copy it further to ensure lua knows that it's the same function
lua_pushcfunction(lua, my_equal);

luaL_newmetatable(lua, "B");
// removed __index for clarity
luaL_register(lua, NULL, mylib_B);

// Now we register __eq separately
lua_pushstring(lua, "__eq");
lua_pushvalue(lua, -3); // Copy my_equal on top
lua_settable(lua, -3); // Register it under B metatable
lua_pop(lua, 1);


luaL_newmetatable(lua, "A");
// removed __index for clarity
luaL_register(lua, NULL, mylib_A);

lua_pushstring(lua, "__eq");
lua_pushvalue(lua, -3); // Copy my_equal on top
lua_settable(lua, -3); // Register it under A metatable

luaL_register(lua, "mylib", mylib); // where mylib is a bunch of static functions
```